Ansible: poetry run make in python venv - permission denied
I try to automate some shell commands - specifically to install a software.
The commands that work in terminal (on ubuntu) by hand are:
sudo su - user
# install all necessary packages
# install all dependencies to virtual env
source /home/user/.venv/bin/activate
# clone the repo
cd repo
poetry install
./configure
poetry run make -j
# more code

and it always fails at
    - name: poetry run make
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        source /home/user/.venv/bin/activate
        poetry run make -j$(nproc) VERBOSE=1
      args:
        chdir: /home/user/repo
        executable: /bin/bash
      become: yes
      become_user: user

I get a weird error:
TASK [Build with make] ********************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.178.46]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "source /home/user/.venv/bin/activate\npoetry run make -j$(nproc) VERBOSE=1\n", "delta": "0:00:03.812497", "end": "2024-07-21 21:01:38.253776", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2024-07-21 21:01:34.441279", "stderr": "make: 1: Permission denied\nmake: *** [plugins/Makefile:235: plugins/sql-schema_gen.h] Error 127\nmake: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....", "stderr_lines": ["make: 1: Permission denied", "make: *** [plugins/Makefile:235: plugins/sql-schema_gen.h] Error 127", "make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs...."], 

This looks to me as if something went wrong with user management or privileges escalation. But no matter what I try I don't seem to get it running.
I have also tried with the same result:
    - name: Build with make
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        /home/user/.venv/bin/poetry run make -j$(nproc) VERBOSE=1
      args:
        chdir: /home/user/repo
        executable: /bin/bash
      become: yes
      become_user: user
      environment:
        VIRTUAL_ENV: /home/user/.venv
        PATH: /home/user/.venv/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}

is there a better way or one that works at least?
